# What does the color of the Iron Fist mean?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-fist-2017, iron-fist

In the *Iron Fist* TV show, the main character Danny Rand is the Iron Fist, the protector of the legendary city K'un L'un. As such, he can concentrate his energy in his fist, which then glows yellow and gives him extreme strength. Strong enough to blow a concrete wall in one blow or to hurt Luke Cage.

We can see a few other Iron Fists in Season 2 (spoiler ahead). The first one (let's call him A) is

> Davos, who is Danny's childhood friend in K'un L'un. They competed for the title of Iron Fist.

His fist is red. I first understood it as the symbol that he is not a true Iron Fist, since he didn't beat the Mystical Dragon that traditionally grants the power of the Iron Fist but

> stole the power from Danny, through a mystical ritual made by (surprisingly good at fighting!) New York tattoo artists...

The second one (let's call her B) is

> Colleen, Danny's girlfriend and martial artist.

I believed her fist should also glow red since she got her power by a similar ritual than the character mentioned above. But her fist is white when she uses the power of the Iron Fist.

**What explains the difference of colors of the Iron Fist?**

My theories so far:

1. A's power is corrupted, since he got it by an illegitimate method. Symbolized by a red fist. On the other hand, though B got her power by a similar mean, she has a *pure* white fist, maybe because the gain of her power was somewhat allowed by Danny. And also because she may be

> the descendant of the first female Iron Fist.

2. An Iron Fist's true color was always assumed to be white, but it is explained in Season 1 and in *the Defenders* show that Danny does not fully master his power and has doubts about his duty and place in the world. So yellow fist means uncomplete Iron Fist.
3. Every Iron Fist has his/her own color, depending on his/her personality.
4. Netflix's Marvel TV shows suck at explaining and keeping consistent their mystical elements. See all the questions about the Hand and Elektra on this site.

The show did not explain it so far, so I will accept Words of God, or answers from the comics.

Comment: I interpreted this differently still, the fist is a manifestation of chi(Danny says this several times). Davos was driven by rage and dishonor at losing the fist to Danny, and that rage was what tainted his chi and the color of his fist red (the color of anger). Danny is constantly off-balance, his desire for the fist was driven by loss and wanting a place to belong. He leaves Kun'lun for the same reason, and his chi reflects this, giving it a yellow-orange tint. Colleen on the other hand, has achieved balance and is at peace, It's part of why Danny asks her to train him. (continued...)

Comment: So her chi is a pure white light, composed of all the other colors in the spectrum. Colleen's chi is not overpowered by any one emotion or trait.

Comment: @AAlig Please make that an answer.

Comment: @StephenS It's a low quality answer, to be honest. It's based on both my interpretation and the comic book lore, which has already been shown to differ from the television continuity.

Comment: @AAlig IMHO, it’s better than the two we have below.

Comment: @AAlig: since the show is over, an answer from the comics is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I agree the fist is a manifestation of chi, Colleen’s  fist was white because she didn’t have any  envy, spite or malice over wanting it in fact she was only holding  on to the power till Danny figured out what he wanted to do hopefully there’s another season that explains it when she gives it back to Danny

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Lack of envy, malice and spite might explain Colleen, but why is Danny's yellow and Davos' red?

Comment: Extending on this, I believe Davos had red fist because of his major Anger issues, whereas Yellow Fist of Danny is still a question. Yellow is often considered the colour of fear. But I doubt Danny was scared of anything.

Answer (score -3):

As far My theory..
Dany defeated the Dragon Shawlao and he was worthy of the Iron Fist for which he got the colour yellow.
Dawos stole the power stole the power from Danny and his heart was corrupted and mind also which explains the colour red for anger and corruption
Elene face was White because her mind and soul was both pure which refers to the colour white for purity and righteousness...

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Two things; you skip over why Danny's fist is yellow, and this would be a better answer if you could give some evidence for this, so it's more than just a personal theory.